# how to render datetime from database and convert it into seperate integer like day,month,year

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
dt= (DateTime)dr[0];
o = (int)dt.Day;
h =(int) dt.Month;
f = (int)dt.Year;
if ((e.Day.Date.Date == new DateTime(f,h,o )))
{
   e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

I am trying this code but it is not working....& want to Color retrived data

Comment: where is your code in? what is the `e`?

Comment: e is day render event

Comment: Have you checked the value in `e.Day`? What is it? You can set break point and watch variables OR you can simply check with `MessageBox.Show`. You should clearly state "what is not working" and "what do you expect"?

Comment: Actually I want to display date which we render from database show it in red color in calender.......

Comment: what is the `e`? which event this code is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    dt= (DateTime)dr[0];
    if(dt!= null)
    {       
        if(dt == e.Day.Date)
          {
             e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
          }
    }
}
```

hope this help you